# How to store the value of a SQL box into a PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to select the data and then store it's information inside of a variable. I feel this is very simple but I can't seem to get it to do it. When I run the below code the result is blank.

Thanks for any help.

```
$sql = "SELECT `$dateName` FROM `$user` WHERE hour=1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $x = $row["`$dateName`"];
        echo $x;
    }
}
```

Here is my Create Table code:

```
/* CREATE TABLE FOR NEW USER */
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `$newUser` (
            hour INT(6) NOT NULL
        )";
/* CHECK CREATION */
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error . ".<br><br>";
}

/* ADD TABLE FOR TODAYS DATE */
$sql = "ALTER TABLE `$user`
            ADD `$dateName` text";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Todays Date entered!";
} else {
    echo "Date already Exists" . "<br><br>";
}
```

Comment: `$dateName` and `$user` are PHP variables; what values do you assign to them before you perform the query?

Comment: $dateName = 05012016 (todays date)
$user = Benjamin_Lawson (the users name)

Comment: That's completely wrong. For your **`SELECT`** to be valid, `$dateName` needs to be the name of a column in your table, and `$user` needs to contain the name of the table. Show us the definition of the table you're trying to query. Also, please explain clearly what the query is intended to accomplish. (That's as much for your benefit as for ours. If you can't explain it clearly you need to rethink it.)

Comment: $user is the name of my table. and $dateName is the name of the column in my table.

Comment: You have a table for each user with a column for each date? What the heck are you trying to do? Please post your `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: Just a small web app I am making to practice what I have learned. I understand this is not the most efficient way to do this however it is just a quick and dirty way for me to use what I have learned. I don't plan for this app to ever be used by the masses.

Comment: Fine. Please post your `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: /* CREATE TABLE FOR NEW USER */
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE `$newUser` (
  hour INT(6) NOT NULL
  )";
   /* CHECK CREATION */
   if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   } else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error . ".<br><br>";
   }


/* ADD TABLE FOR TODAYS DATE */
  $sql = "ALTER TABLE `$user`
  ADD `$dateName` text";
  
  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Todays Date entered!";
   } else {
    echo "Date already Exists" . "<br><br>";
   }

Comment: This is my first post on stack overflow. I am not sure how to post my code in the proper format.

Comment: Click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36962419/edit) link at the bottom of your question and then add the `CREATE TABLE` statement there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x will always be empty because of the ` you're adding to the key when you access $row:

```
$x = $row["`$dateName`"];
           ^         ^ remove ticks (You can also remove ")
```

Comment: Wow. FuzzyTree you are great! Thank you so much! :) Yes, I understand completely... such a simple error :). Sorry guys, I just starting out here. But this problem had been bugging me for a few hours now and I needed some support.